# Horizon Ingestion

Tags: horizon, server

We hosted horizon in our own network, the size of storage is increasing dramatically.
Is there anyway that we can start ingesting only from a specific date?

Comment: In short - yes. You can specify the date from or a recent period.
Sorry, I don't remember settings names at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much, I searched the everything and I got nothing. there is only one option I got, which is HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT.

Comment: That's the one!